# How to check a check box automatically on vb.net asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have to insert some data value and value like this picture on insert.aspx

[image]

And how i show like this to update the data update.aspx

[image]

So how to make check box on update.aspx check automatic like on insert.aspx

on Insert.aspx.vb

Protected Sub insertdata()
        Dim cls As New connections

```
    cls.openconnections()
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = cls.cn

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_inserttrainer"


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtKode.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama", txtnama.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", txtstatus.SelectedValue)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alamat", txtalamat.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telp", txttel.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hp", txthp.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cls.closeconnection()

End Sub
 Protected Sub savedatamateri()


    Dim cbterpilih As Boolean = False
    Dim cb As CheckBox = Nothing
    Dim n As Integer = 0

    Do Until n = gridsecond.Rows.Count
        cb = gridsecond.Rows.Item(n).FindControl("chkStatus")
        If cb IsNot Nothing AndAlso cb.Checked Then
            cbterpilih = True


            Dim cls As New connections
            cls.openconnections()
            Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = cls.cn

            cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into m_trainer_detil (trainer_id, materi_id)"
            cmd.CommandText &= "values(@triner, @materi)"

            Dim com As HiddenField = CType(gridsecond.Rows(n).FindControl("HiddenField2"), HiddenField)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@triner", txtKode.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@materi", com.Value)


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cls.closeconnection()

        End If

        n += 1
    Loop
End Sub

 Protected Sub insert_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles insert.Click
        If txtalamat.Text = "" Then
            labelran.Text = "Tolong isi Alamat"
        ElseIf txtemail.Text = "" Then
            labelran.Text = "Tolong isi Email"
        ElseIf txtnama.Text = "" Then
            labelran.Text = "Tolong isi Nama"
        ElseIf txttel.Text = "" Then
            labelran.Text = "Tolong isi Telepon"
        ElseIf txthp.Text = "" Then
            labelran.Text = "Tolong isi Handphone"
        Else
            insertdata()
            savedatamateri()
            listhendle()
        End If


    End Sub
```

and for update.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            listhendle()
            listmateri()

    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub listhendle()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim cls As New connections

    ds = cls.returndataset("select * from [m_trainer] ")

    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
        ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).NewRow)
    End If
    griddata.DataSource = ds
    griddata.DataBind()

End Sub
Protected Sub listmateri()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim cls As New connections

    ds = cls.returndataset("select * from [m_materi] ")

    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
        ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).NewRow)
    End If
    gridsecond.DataSource = ds
    gridsecond.DataBind()

End Sub


Protected Sub griddata_SelectedIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSelectEventArgs) Handles griddata.SelectedIndexChanging

        Dim kode As HiddenField = CType(griddata.Rows(e.NewSelectedIndex).FindControl("HiddenField1"), HiddenField)

        txtKode.Text = kode.Value
        txtnama.Text = Replace(griddata.Rows(e.NewSelectedIndex).Cells(1).Text, "&nbsp;", "")
        txtalamat.Text = Replace(griddata.Rows(e.NewSelectedIndex).Cells(2).Text, "&nbsp;", "")
        txttel.Text = Replace(griddata.Rows(e.NewSelectedIndex).Cells(3).Text, "&nbsp;", "")
        txthp.Text = Replace(griddata.Rows(e.NewSelectedIndex).Cells(4).Text, "&nbsp;", "")
        txtstatus.SelectedValue = Replace(griddata.Rows(e.NewSelectedIndex).Cells(5).Text, "&nbsp;", "")
        txtemail.Text = Replace(griddata.Rows(e.NewSelectedIndex).Cells(6).Text, "&nbsp;", "")



    End Sub
```

But i don't know how  connect materi with database
Thank You

Comment: We appreciate the screenshots, but sample code-behind of your update.aspx, especially code on how you populate the last table in update.aspx, would be more highly appreciated.

Comment: How did you make it in insert.aspx? Is it a data bound column? Please add some code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are storing the materi_id in the table m_trainer.  So it looks like you would need to set up an OnRowDataBound event on your "gridSecond" GridView.  Within the OnRowDatabound event get a dataset for the selected trainer_id and if the materi_id exists within that dataset set its checked value as true.